# Dynamic page filled with content depending on the previous page

Tags: php, articles, category, joomla-4

I am kinda new as a developer and I want to achieve the following in Joomla. The idea is that I have a category->sub category->products. The category and subcategory will be added in joomla and maintained from there. The products will come from a 3rd site (through DB or API request). The question is, is it possible to just create only one article in joomla which will be called i.e "Product article" and everytime the user clicks on a subcategory then to be able to get as parameter the subcategory id and build the product page with content(that comes from the response to the 3rd site)? And then from the product page that is builded dynamically to be able to get to the specific product page.

I hope I explained it right what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, this is possible, but this question is Too Broad.  This is the type of requirements dump that professional developers get paid to do. If you intend to do this yourself, please make a start and ask a narrow question when you become stuck. Please take our [tour].

Comment: That would be a dirty and poorly maintainable approach. You should create a proper component instead.